# VBA PowerPoint author protect

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, properties

I know from the Excel, that it is possible to write a VBA to protect the author name, so no one can change it and take credit for your work.

I have once read that the Excel VBA is something like when the workbook open, or save of closed it will automatically change to the name defined in the VBA.

Is it possible do create similar VBA for PowerPoint? so no one can change the author name in the presentation properties?

Thanks for helping

/Sanne

Comment: "I know from the Excel, that it is possible to write a VBA to protect the author name, so no one can change it and take credit for your work" - could you please share that code? It's unclear what exactly you think of.

Answer (score 1):

The Author Name is one of PowerPoint's built-in document properties. It can be set manually or by code but can't be protected against change.

There are ways of hiding information such that nobody but a fairly sophisticated user could detect it; if you were to hide your name that way, and came across an illicit copy of your work, you could at least prove it was actually yours, not matter what the Author Name says.

Another approach would be to add a very small shape on the slide master with your name in it, perhaps just off the bottom of the master, then use an add-in to make the shape unselectable. Chirag Dalal has one called ShapeLocker:

http://officeoneonline.com/shapelocker/shapelocker.html